# Laravel not return BelongsTo

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Thanks guys I have two tables one named Produto and another with ProdutoCategoria name. When I make the relationship the models, only the ProdutoCategoria object returns the Produdo, but the Produto does not return the object ProdutoCategoria, why?.

```
    class ProdutoCateg extends Model
{
    public function produtos(){
        return $this->hasMany('app\Produto');
    }
}



class Produto extends Model
{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('app\ProdutoCateg');
    }
}


class Fktables extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('produtos', function ($table){
            $table->foreign('id_produto_categs')->references('id')->on('produto_categs');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: What does Produto  return then?

Comment: Can you show us your migrations? Not only the foreign key creation

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `foreign key` field in relation, Laravel is not able to guess it, since you haven't followed naming convention DB schema.

```
class Produto extends Model
{
    public function categoria(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProdutoCateg', 'id_produto_categs');
    }
}
```

**Example**

**Product** model should have a table named `products`
and **ProductCategory** model should have a table named `product_categories`,
now to create relation with category use `table_name (singular) + _id`, which will be `product_category_id` in this case. I hope it makes sense.

In order to make this work automatically, you will need change FK as `produto_categ_id` on `produtos` table.

Answer (score 0):

You should try change `app` to `App`
Example:

```
public function produtos {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Produto');
}
```